# setting up Microsoft Unity 5.6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

Does anyone know of a site that helps me setup Microsoft Unity DI in Asp.net I want to do Unity 5.6 but I can't find any documentation on how to set it up in ASP.net WebApi

https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/

https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/tree/v5.x

Comment: Time to find a DI container that actually has documentation.

Comment: I'd agree with that statement have a suggestion ?

Comment: What prevents you from using the current nuget packages, namely this: https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection ?

Comment: I have it does zero setup